# Text on center of menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

As shown in the picture below, within the highlighted green area, is there a way to put a text in the center of the menu bar?

[image]

Comment: What 'text'...?

Comment: based on your intention, for example it is just an example on center

Answer (score 2):

[AnyBar with Text](https://github.com/ttscoff/AnyBar) should do what you want. I have used the project it is forked from (AnyBar) to successfully monitor things.

This free app runs in the background and there are a variety of ways to issue it commands, including from the command line, AppleScript, or through programming languages like Go, Node, PHP, Ruby, Java, and Python.

Edited to add: Note that the text won't be in the center of the menubar, per se, but it will be toward the "inside" of the status icons on the right hand side, towards the middle.

Comment: thanks for help but I have found another software as well, I'm looking for being centered

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname If it works, please post it in an answer so others can benefit as well